# Laptop browsers scaling websites for smaller display?

Tags: windows-8, laptop, display, windows-8.1, resolution

I'm really not sure how to word this question.  Basically though, I recently purchased a newish laptop (Samsung Ativ Book 8), which has a 15.6" 1920x1080 display, and happens to be the first 1080p laptop I've owned.

For my desktop PC, I use a 27" 1920x1080 display.  Both are running Win8.1.  Obviously the physical size of my desktop monitor is much bigger, but I appear to have a whole lot more pixel real-estate on the desktop than on the laptop.  It would seem that the OS is resizing certain screen elements to be appropriately sized for a smaller screen, which is understandable (since everything would probably appear microscopic otherwise!).

However, my main issue lies in the fact that browsers seem to be scaled as well.  I do a lot of web development/design, and I would like to see what my designs will actually look like on a 1080p display as I build them.  Sometimes I want to take screenshots and experiment with things in photoshop, but all of my screenshots have my web elements scaled (150px high div is captured as 180ish px).  This is getting really frustrating.

Is there a way to toggle this scaling in Windows 8.1?  It doesn't appear to be a browser specific setting either, since every one of my browsers does the exact same thing, and none of them seem to have any settings related to this.

Comment: http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/extremewindows/archive/2013/07/15/windows-8-1-dpi-scaling-enhancements.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I realize this question is almost a year old, but maybe someone can benefit from this.

To adjust display scaling in Windows 8.1, go to "Control Panel" > "Appearance and Personalization" > "Display" then choose "Let me choose one scaling level for all my displays" then "100%"